# Does Asus M580VD support NVMe SSD? Refer Image

Tags: ssd, asus-laptop, nvme

Does Asus M580VD support NVMe SSD?
[SSD port on motherboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10rkN.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It supports M.2 SATA SSD, you can check in your motherboard manual online.

Details here :
https://www.laptopmain.com/asus-vivobook-pro-15-n580vd-disassembly-ssd-ram-hdd-upgrade-options/
Does not support NVMe SSD
https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Monitors-and-Memory/SSD-for-my-Asus-N580VD/td-p/373599

The 128GB SATA3 M.2 SSD is wrapped in a metal shield. If necessary, you can replace it with a 512GB SATA3 SSD. On Asus official website we only see the laptop comes with SATA3 SSD, so I think it should **not** be compatible with NVMe SSD.
[image]